# Why does Word 2010 print even if I cancel the dialog?

Tags: c#, printing, office-interop, office-2010

I'm using the Visual Studio 2010 Office Tools to "remote control" Word 2010. This works great, I can also print the document I create. However, when I show Word's print dialog, the document is printed even if I press the cancel button. Why is that so and how can I properly react to the cancel button being pressed?

My code is as follows:

```
public void Print(string printerName, bool showPrintDialog)
{
    if (m_wordApp == null || m_wordDoc == null)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("...");

    object missing = System.Type.Missing;
    object varTrue = true;

    if (printerName != null)
        m_wordApp.ActivePrinter = printerName;

    if (showPrintDialog)
    {
        Word.Dialog varDlg = m_wordApp.Application.Dialogs[Word.WdWordDialog.wdDialogFilePrint];
        varDlg.Show(ref missing);
    }
    else
    {
        m_wordDoc.PrintOut(ref varTrue, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I was using an old version of the code to debug the application, where the line

```
m_wordDoc.PrintOut(ref ...);
```

was not wrapped in an `else` block. Once I debugged the correct version of my code, the print dialog behaved as expected.

Sorry to interrupt ...